# Android how to get content for saving data on external/internal storage on a serivce?

Tags: android, service

The class "Data_Controler" is initialized by a activity with a button.
The class do some sensor jobs and save data to the external or internal storage.

the Startbutton simply does:

```
data_controler = new Data_Controler(this.getApplicationContext());
```

I used in the Data_Controler class:

public class Data_Controler implements Sensor_Manager.OnSensorChangedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks{...}

the methode:

```
public File createInternalSavePathFolderAndFile(String filename){

    String path = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+
            "/Android/data" + "/com.mypackage.myprog" + "/files";

    File dir = new File(path);
    dir.mkdirs();
    final File file = new File(dir, new String(filename + ".xml"));
    return file;

}
```

That works so far.

**Now i want to have the Data_Controler without a Startbutton, to run it on its own without a UI.**

I used to extend it as a Service and added in the manifest the service:

Starting Service works, but if i try to call methodes wich uses "context" like:

```
context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()
```

it always returns null and crash the app. I already replaced the constructor with:

```
this.context = this.getApplicationContext();
```

But this.getApplicationContext() also returns null in the Service;

Ideas what iam doing wrong?

Comment: 'context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+
            "/Android/data" + "/com.mypackage.myprog" + "/files";'. That is a very strange path. That would become'/data/data/com.mypackage.myprog/files/Android/data/com.mypackage.myprog/files'. Why would you do that?

Comment: How and where do you start the service?

Comment: hi, the path ist just fine and not the problem. The result of the path was for example: \Phone\Android\data\com.mypackage.myprog\files

Comment: i tried serveral ways to start the service - all end up in the same problem with the context wich is null. First was with a broadcast receiver class wich calls public class ServiceStartup extends BroadcastReceiver:
        Intent service = new Intent(context, Data_Controler_Service.class);
        context.startService(service);  Than i tried: startService(new Intent(this, Data_Controler.class)) from the activity with the button

Comment: ' \Phone\Android......'. Such a path does not exist on an Android device. Where did you see that path?

Comment: Service is a Context. So you can use this.

Comment: okay this returns some content, but  i still get the erro:    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.getFilesDir(ContextWrapper.java:205) when i try to read some file or try to get some path

Answer (score 0):

Okay i got the problem , i used a default constructor and the onCreate methode . The onCreate was empty , i have done everything in the default constructor.

The default constructor was also called but the initialisations was didnt work well for some reason. 
I put the initialisations into the on create methode an everything is working now.